# how to run NiFi-toolkit docker image

Tags: docker, apache-nifi

am trying to start a container for `nifi-toolkit`, I get the error message `No program option specified. Options available include:  encrypt-config s2s flow-analyzer node-manager tls-toolkit file-manager notify zk-migrator cli` but, am not sure where/how to set these values

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a terminal and run:

```
docker run --rm apache/nifi-toolkit file-manager
```

This is an example for file-manager option. Change it for different options. You can also add parameter(s) after file-manager.

Explanation:

This image has an entrypoint defined. Meaning a program that runs by default when you start a container based on it.

You can see it with:

```
docker pull apache/nifi-toolkit
docker run --rm --entrypoint cat apache/nifi-toolkit /opt/sh/docker-entrypoint.sh
```